# Trying to automatically run a method without having the user click the button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-props

```
    {!this.props.account ? (
           <button onClick={this.props.onSignIn}>Sign In</button>
      ) : (
    // Otherwise show the homepage
```

Replacing the onClick with a way to just have the this.props.onSignIn happen just once.

The user should not have to click on a button to log in, but once the page loads, it should just check if the user is authenticated, and if not then run the onSignIn method just once

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentDidMount is the lifecycle hook to run code once after mounting:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.props.account) {
    this.props.onSignIn()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hooks, `useEffect` is what you are looking for.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!this.props.account) {
    this.props.onSignIn();
  }
}, [])
```

Notice the second argument of `useEffect`, it accepts a set of dependencies, upon the changes on those dependencies, the `useEffect` hook will run again.

Since we are passing nothing, (an empty array), the hook will run only once when the component mounts.

Read more about hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html